# How to count and sum rows form a table grouping by a column?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables:

- **Products** (id, name, category_id, ...)
- **Categories** (id, ...)
- **Sales** (id_product, id_user, selled, date_sale, quantity)

---

### I'm trying to get the most selled product:

```
SELECT P.`id`, P.`name`, C.`name` as catName, SUM(S.`quantity`) 
FROM `products` AS P, `categories` AS C, `sales` AS S 
WHERE P.`category_id` = C.`id` 
    AND P.`id` = S.`id_product` 
    AND P.`id` IN ( 
                    SELECT `id_product` FROM `sales` 
                    WHERE `selled`=1
                  ) 
LIMIT 8
```

[image: Result of the query]

Gives me all the information i want, except for the fact that **quantities are not grouped/summed by id_product**.

---

So, to solve that i'm **trying with** `SUM(S.quantity)` **and** group by id_product:

```
SELECT P.`id`, P.`name`, C.`name` as catName, SUM(S.`quantity`) 
FROM `products` AS P, `categories` AS C, `sales` AS S 
WHERE P.`category_id` = C.`id` 
    AND P.`id` = S.`id_product` 
    AND P.`id` IN ( 
                    SELECT `id_product` FROM `sales` 
                    WHERE `selled`=1
                  ) 
LIMIT 8 
GROUP BY P.`id`
```

After the query, **i'm receiving an error**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY P.`id`' at line 3

### Is there a way to achieve what i'm trying to? Why does group by can't be used like this?

Comment: GROUP BY comes before LIMIT

Comment: Thanks Mike, it worked. Answer so that i can reward you.

Comment: Note: the 1:M relationships between products, categories and sales will artificially inflate the counts and sums.  you have to SUM/count values before the joins using inline views!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY comes before LIMIT

Happy Holidays!